# jQuery: too much recursion But I need recursion for minesweeper

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am relatively new to javascript. I am trying to code my web version of minesweeper. Here is a recursive function I needed, and it looks to work fine until browser gives this "too much recursion" error. The problem is that i need that recursion. Is there any other way to code minesweeper?  Here is the demo: http://altynachar.com/minesweeper/

I can post my php code if needed.

```
function recursive(id){
                var id = id;
                //Determine what kind of cell this is: Clean, Bomb or Adjasent to bomb
                if($("#"+id).hasClass("adj")== true)
                    var under = "adj";
                if($("#"+id).hasClass("bomb")==true)
                    var under = "bomb";
                if($("#"+id).hasClass("clean")==true)
                    var under = "clean";

                //open up the cell          
                $("#"+id).hide();
                $("#under_"+id).show(); 

                //if it is bomb, open up whole grid and button for restart
                if(under == 'bomb')
                {       
                    $(".cover").hide();
                    $(".under").show();
                    $("body").append("<br /><input type='button' value='restart' onClick='javascript:window.location.reload();' />");
                } else {        

                    //if it is clean cell       
                    if(under == "clean")
                    {
                        //get all the adjasent cell ids
                        var split = id.split('-');
                        var row = parseInt(split[0]);
                        var col = parseInt(split[1]);
                        var adjasent = new Array();
                        adjasent[0] = (row-1)+"-"+ (col+1);
                        adjasent[1] =  row +"-"+(col+1);
                        adjasent[2] = (row+1)+"-"+(col+1);
                        adjasent[3] = (row+1)+"-"+col;
                        adjasent[4] = (row+1)+"-"+(col-1);
                        adjasent[5] =  row+"-"+(col-1);
                        adjasent[6] = (row -1)+"-"+(col-1);
                        adjasent[7] = (row -1)+"-"+col;

                        //loop through adjasent cells
                        for(var i=0; i<adjasent.length; i++)
                        {
                            var split2 = adjasent[i].split('-');
                            var row2 = parseInt(split2[0]);
                            var col2 = parseInt(split2[1]);

                            //check if cell is existent
                            if(row2 > 0 && row2 < 17)
                            {
                                if(col2 > 0 && col2 < 17)
                                {
                                    //perform recursion
                                    var adj = adjasent[i];
                                    recursive(adj);
                                } 
                            }                               
                        }
                    }
                } 
            }
```

Comment: Why do you need recursion for minesweeper?  I may be missing something, but I can't think of a reason you would need recursion at all.

Comment: I like that you give each element that is a bomb the class `bomb` ;)

Comment: @Herms: you're not missing anything.

Comment: @Herms, @Chris: Recursion is the obvious way to do the automatic reveal of all cells next to a cell that has no mine and touches no mines. It can trivially be replaced with a queue. I used recursion here for brevity: http://js1k.com/2011-dysentery/demo/971

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that if you have 2 clean cells next to each other your code will get in an infinite recursion.

Each iteration recurses to all adjacent cells.  So say cell A and B are next to each other, and both are clean.  A will call recurse to B, which will then recurse to A, which recurses to B, and so on.

You can either try to clean up your recursion so that it doesn't look at cells that were already seen, or remove the recursion.  You can accomplish the same thing by adding any unseen clean cells to a queue, and just keep popping off the end of the queue until it's empty.  That might make it easier to avoid checking the same cell twice too.

---

Also, *please* don't build up strings just to split them into separate data later.  Instead of:

```
adjasent[0] = (row-1)+"-"+ (col+1);
/* ... */
var split2 = adjasent[i].split('-');
var row2 = parseInt(split2[0]);
var col2 = parseInt(split2[1]);
```

just do

```
adjacent[0] = { row: row-1, col: col+1 };
/* ... */
var row2 = adjacent[0].row
var col2 = adjacent[0].col
```

Comment: Thank you very much,  I got what you mean! I guess I should have told that I am relatively new to programming, not to js

Answer (score 1):

Your recursion is essentially a depth-first search.  The problem is that you do not account for visited cells.  In other words, say you have 2 cells, A & B:

`A` `B`

When you click on `A`, it searches for adjacent cells, and comes up with a list containing `B`.  You recurse, and then look for neighbors of `B`, which is a list containing `A`, and then you recurse again.  This cycle never ends.

You need to mark each cell you visit and return if it has already been visited:

```
function recursive(id){
    var id = id;

    if( $("#"+id).hasClass('visited') ) {
         return;
    }

    $("#"+id).addClass('visited');

    ...

}
```

Then you need to remove 'visited' from everything after recursion is complete:

```
$('div').removeClass('visited');
```

Comment: i used your way, and now it is working fine. I uploaded it to the server as well. Thank you for guiding me. I just dont see why would I need to remove class visited?

Comment: If you don't clear the 'visited' status of the cell after a search, then the next time you click a cell and this method is called, then all of the cells searched before will still be considered 'visited' and so will never be searched during the current instance of this method.

Comment: @Nazar: Sorry about the late reply.  Zéychin is correct in his explanation.  However, in the case of your particular use, you would not necessarily need it, as once an empty cell is visited, it will not be visited by your function again, and non-empty cells do not matter.  You would need to make sure to clear 'visited' whenever you regenerate your board regardless.

Comment: Oh, got it, thanks. Anyway, my board is generated by php script so after refresh those will be cleared automatically. Btw, I used ur way, and now I am almost done :)

Answer (score 0):

Keep a running array of cell id's to check, and delete these values from the array as you check them.

```
        var stack = ["first_id_to_check"];

        function check(id){
            var id = id;
            //Determine what kind of cell this is: Clean, Bomb or Adjasent to bomb
            if($("#"+id).hasClass("adj")== true)
                var under = "adj";
            if($("#"+id).hasClass("bomb")==true)
                var under = "bomb";
            if($("#"+id).hasClass("clean")==true)
                var under = "clean";

            //open up the cell          
            $("#"+id).hide();
            $("#under_"+id).show(); 

            //if it is bomb, open up whole grid and button for restart
            if(under == 'bomb')
            {       
                $(".cover").hide();
                $(".under").show();
                $("body").append("<br /><input type='button' value='restart' onClick='javascript:window.location.reload();' />");
            } else {        

                //if it is clean cell       
                if(under == "clean")
                {
                    //get all the adjasent cell ids
                    var split = id.split('-');
                    var row = parseInt(split[0]);
                    var col = parseInt(split[1]);
                    var adjasent = new Array();
                    adjasent[0] = (row-1)+"-"+ (col+1);
                    adjasent[1] =  row +"-"+(col+1);
                    adjasent[2] = (row+1)+"-"+(col+1);
                    adjasent[3] = (row+1)+"-"+col;
                    adjasent[4] = (row+1)+"-"+(col-1);
                    adjasent[5] =  row+"-"+(col-1);
                    adjasent[6] = (row -1)+"-"+(col-1);
                    adjasent[7] = (row -1)+"-"+col;

                    //loop through adjasent cells
                    for(var i=0; i<adjasent.length; i++)
                    {
                        var split2 = adjasent[i].split('-');
                        var row2 = parseInt(split2[0]);
                        var col2 = parseInt(split2[1]);

                        //check if cell is existent
                        if(row2 > 0 && row2 < 17)
                        {
                            if(col2 > 0 && col2 < 17)
                            {
                                stack.push(adjasent[i]);
                            } 
                        }                               
                    }
                }
            } 
        }

        while(stack[0]!==undefined) {
            check(stack[0]);
            stack.splice(0,1);
        }
```

Comment: That should stop the infinite recursion, but it will instead be an infinite loop.  This code will still check cells it's already checked before.  You'd need to add another variable that keeps track of which IDs it's already seen, and check against that before adding to the stack.

Comment: I'm only adding ids to the stack as he would have called the function recursively, so if he has the logic to prevent the recursive algorithm from performing redundant calls then he should have the same measures available on the array. Which I see he does not.